# PHP table (Date) dynamic color change based on validity

Tags: php, mysql

```
<div class="table-responsive">  
<table id="Well_CAT" class="table table-striped table-bordered">                              
<thead> <th>Client_Contract_Number</th>
<th>Currently_Using</th>
<th>MBPS_EAM_Number_RIGT</th>
<th>Model_and_Type</th>
<th>LFour_Yearly</th>
<th>Six_Monthly</th>
<th>One_Yearly</th>
<th>One_and_Half_Yearly</th>
<th>Two_Yearly</th>
<th>Two_and_Half_Yearly</th>
<th>Three_Yearly</th>
<th>Three_and_Half_Yearly</th>
<th>Four_Yearly</th>
<th>Remarks</th>
</thead>  
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?><tr>  
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Client_Contract_Number']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Currently_Using']; ?></td>
 <td><? echo $rows['MBPS_EAM_Number_RIGT']; ?></td>
 <td><? echo $rows['Model_and_Type']; ?></td>
 <td><? echo $rows['LFour_Yearly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Six_Monthly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['One_Yearly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['One_and_Half_Yearly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Two_Yearly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Two_and_Half_Yearly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Three_Yearly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Three_and_Half_Yearly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Four_Yearly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Remarks']; ?></td>
  </tr>  
    <?php
     }
     ?>
  </table>
```

Below is my table, it is to track the validity of certificates, columns from Lfour yearly till Fouryearly are date fields, i would like to conditional color format these fields based on validity... Like If valid - Green, Expired - Red.

Comment: What defines if a date is valid or not?

Comment: If current date is less than the date in the field then the date is valid, else expired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PHP >= 5.2.0 you can use the DateTime class as such:

```
if (new DateTime() > new DateTime("2010-05-15 16:00:00")) {
    # current time is greater than 2010-05-15 16:00:00
    # in other words, 2010-05-15 16:00:00 has passed
}
```

The string passed to the DateTime constructor is parsed according to these rules.

Here is an example with your code:

```
<td class="exdate" style="color:<?php echo (new DateTime() > new DateTime($rows['Six_Monthly'])) ? 'red' : 'green'; ?>;" ><? echo $rows['Six_Monthly']; ?></td>
```

Comment: Really..Thank you for the help...,

Comment: I have another issue.. now my table dates are in YYY/MM/DD format, i would like to change it it DD/MMM/YY format,I managed to do it for each column.. it would be better if i can do it for entire table all at once. (I have more than 15 tables to process) Please help me with this same example.. so that i can do it for all others. Sorry if t it is a stupid question,..Cozz I am new to PHP  :(

Comment: You should ask another public question :)